# Can posture affect the jaw position?

Tags: dentistry, posture, jaw

How are jaw, teeth and other related part of body ( more precisely, head ) affected by bad posture?

Can a bad jaw position be solved in 'nature' way, by exercise, correction of posture of neck, so head even when relaxed can't get in 'down' position where teeth are closed? Should one go to physical practioner to examine one‘s overall posture?

Comment: Although you show effort not making this question individualised, it still is. I will cut it down so that this doesn’t request personal medical advice for *subject*. Please revert my edit if you disagree.

Comment: An orthodontist may be able to help you with this one.

Comment: See a Physical Therapist - the Graston Technique works wonders for TMJ cases.  Obviously a PT can help you correct your postural issues too.  See here:   http://kinetichealth.ca/treating-temporomandibular-joint-disorder/

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma i guess you are right. I just want to point to things that might be related with question.

Answer (score -2):

Here you have

1 - https://occlusionconnections.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/gnm-approach-compilation-clayton-a-chan-dds.pdf

2 - https://occlusionconnections.com/gneuromuscular-dentistry-gnm/physiologic-rest

It seems i have to write more to my answer be acepted

Comment: Links will rot eventually. It would be great if you could summarise what those two articles say in your answer *and* provide a link to the articles